# dynamic sql in mysql stored proceure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a generic sql procedure that can execute any string as a sql statement.

Here is the procedure definition.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS execute_dynamic_sql;
CREATE PROCEDURE execute_dynamic_sql (IN sql_query longtext)
BEGIN
SELECT sql_query;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
```

I am calling the above function like this

```
mysql> call execute_dynamic_sql('show tables');
    -> //
+-------------+
| sql_query   |
+-------------+
| show tables |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
mysql> #
```

Can somebody tell me why is the error coming ?

Comment: ... Why are you writing a procedure to execute a query? Why not just execute the query?

Comment: I have to make a lot of sql statements and execute it. So, I moved the 4 common lines to another procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to indicate the difference between [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) and routine parameters [13.1.15. CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html), are different variables.

In your example `@sql_query` is `NULL` and `sql_query` is assigned to `SHOW TABLES`.

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER//

CREATE PROCEDURE `execute_dynamic_sql` (IN `sql_query` LONGTEXT)
BEGIN
  SET @`sql_query` := `sql_query`;
  PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`sql_query`;
  EXECUTE `stmt`;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
END//

DELIMITER;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aadb1/1)</kbd>